# How to find a JavaScript alert that is already open with WatiN

Tags: javascript, c#, internet-explorer-8, watin, specflow

I'm using a combination of SpecFlow, MSTests for unit testing, and WatiN to drive the browser for testing our web application.

- Visual Studio 2010
- Class Library style project
- SpecFlow
- MS Test
- WatiN

If the user submits our forms without filling in all the required fields a JavaScript `alert` pops up. I'm trying to detect this pop up using WatiN. The SpecFlow step that triggers the alert is different than the SpecFlow step that asserts the pop up exists, so waiting for a WatiN dialog handler doesn't work since the alert is already open.

Example SpecFlow Scenario:

```
Scenario: Form Fields are required
    # This step spawns the alert dialog
    When I click the "Save and Continue" button
    # Test fails here because the alert is already open
    Then I should see the validation error alert
```

The step definition for `When I click the "Save and Continue" button`

```
[When(@"I click the ""(.*)"" button")]
public void WhenIClickTheButton(string buttonText)
{
    Button button = BitWeb.Browser.Button(Find.ByValue(buttonText).Or(Find.ByText(buttonText)));
    Assert.IsTrue(button.Exists, "No button with text '{0}' was found", buttonText);
    button.Click();
    browser.WaitForComplete();
}
```

The step definition for `Then I should see the ... alert`:

```
[Then(@"I should see the validation error alert")]
public void ThenIShouldSeeTheValidationErrorAlert()
{
    var alert = new WatiN.Core.DialogHandlers.AlertDialogHandler();

    alert.WaitUntilExists();

    StringAssert.Contains(alert.Message, "An error has occurred. Check entire", "The validation error alert was not visible.");
}
```

The call to `alert.WaitUntilExists();` throws an exception:

> WatiN.Core.Exceptions.WatiNException: Dialog not available within 30 seconds.

By the time I assert the alert dialog is visible, the DialogHandler doesn't find the alert because it is already open.

How do I find an alert dialog that is already open using WatiN?

**Update #1:** I'm leaning towards a solution that utilizes the `ScenarioContext.Current` object, I'm just not sure how to wire things together so the browser doesn't wait for 30 seconds every time it clicks a button just to see if an alert box pops up.

**Update #2:** After some investigation, clicking the button in one step causes the whole testing framework to pause until the `alert` dialog was dismissed. Clicking the "OK" button dismissed the dialog, which allowed the test runner to advance to the next step where I assert that the dialog box is visible -- a chicken-or-the-egg scenario. Calling `button.ClickNoWait()` fixed the issue.

Comment: Is the dialog an html dialog (jquery type) or is it an actual popup dialog (win32)?

Comment: It's an `alert("message")` dialog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me write a more complete example of this for you:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    //
    // Your class properites/variables
    //
    AlertDialogHandler dialogHandler;


    [DllImport("User32.dll")]
    public static extern Int32 FindWindow(String lpClassName, String lpWindowName);

    //
    // Some methods/functions declarations
    //

    public void SomeInitMethod()
    {
          dialogHandler = new AlertDialogHandler()
          browse.AddDialogHandler(dialogHandler);
    }

    public void SampleMethod()
    {
       IntPtr hwndTmp = (IntPtr)FindWindow("#32770", "Dialog Title");
       WatiN.Core.Native.Windows.Window popUpDialog = new Window(hwndTmp);
       dialogHandler.HandleDialog(popUpDialog);
       //
       // The line above will find the OK button for you and click on it, 
       // from here you continue with the rest of your code.

    }

}
```

Hope this is a little but more clear.

Comment: Ok. This makes more sense. I did a little more Googling and came up with that as well. I'm still playing around trying to get a handle on the alert box. It's mostly because I'm banging my head against the combo of WatiN and SpecFlow.

Comment: Thanks for the help, @ProgrammerV5. +1 and marking this as the answer. I'm going to add an answer of my own (not marked as the answer) giving the actual C# code I used with regards to SpecFlow for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

As it is a Win32 dialog you can get a handle of the window popup (you know the style and you know the title of the window, if you don't know the style you can find out with WinSpy++, just open the tool and point the bulls eye to the alert and it will give you all the details for that window)

```
// #32770 is the window style, just to make the search more confined.
IntPtr hwndTmp = (IntPtr)FindWindow("#32770", "This should be the title of the alert");
Window alertDialog = new Window(hwndTmp);
```

from here on you will be able to treat as a regular Dialog within WatiN (you should use the HandleDialog passing the alertDialog as a parameter, etc. if not clear, let me know and I'll enhance the response).

Comment: What is `FindWindow`? Where is that method declared?

Comment: Also, in which namespace/assembly does the `Window` class exist?

Comment: [DllImport("User32.dll")]
        public static extern Int32 FindWindow(String lpClassName, String lpWindowName);

Comment: Window is part of WatiN.Core.Native.Windows

Comment: I don't have a class with a `FindWindow` method available to me. Is that a static method on a class or an instance method, and if so what class is it a member of?

Comment: Is not a class is a windows API, you need to use it as unmanaged code and you just paste the line I replied above at the beginning of your class code (before any method just for clarity) and it will be available to you as a function.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67046/discussion-between-programmerv5-and-greg-burghardt).

Answer (score 0):

I marked @ProgrammerV5's answer as the real answer, since it led me to this code. I'm only posting this answer because it directly pertains to SpecFlow and WatiN.

I had three different SpecFlow steps that clicked a button, which spawned the `alert`, assert that the alert box has the text I was expecting, and finally one last step to click "OK".

**Example SpecFlow scenario**

```
Scenario: Doing something really important
    When I click the "Save and Continue" button
    Then I should see the validation error alert
    When I click OK in the validation error alert
    Then I continue on with the rest of this Scenario...
```

First, I created a quick helper method to find the `alert` dialog:

**TestProject/Helpers/StepHelper.cs**

```
public static class StepHelper
{
    [DllImport("User32.dll")]
    public static extern Int32 FindWindow(String lpClassName, String lpWindowName);

    public static WatiN.Core.Native.Windows.Window GetAlertBox()
    {
        IntPtr hwndTmp = (IntPtr)FindWindow("#32770", "Message from webpage");
        return new WatiN.Core.Native.Windows.Window(hwndTmp);
    }
}
```

This allows you to grab ahold of the `alert` box in Internet Explorer 8

[image: Screenshot of an alert box in Internet Explorer 8]

**Step definition for `When I click the "Save and Continue" button`:**

```
[When(@"I click the ""(.*)"" button")]
public void WhenIClickTheButton(string buttonText)
{
    Button button = browser.Button(Find.ByValue(buttonText).Or(Find.ByText(buttonText)));
    Assert.IsTrue(button.Exists, "No button with text '{0}' was found", buttonText);
    button.ClickNoWait();
}
```

The call to `button.Click()` or `button.ClickNoWait()` is what spawns the alert box. Just calling the `Click()` method causes WatiN to wait for that event to fully process before it returns from the method call. Since the alert box was open and blocking the page, the click event didn't finish, thereby causing the call to `Click()` to be completely stalled. I got around this by calling `ClickNoWait()` which is a "fire and forget" way to click an element on the page. Now the alert box pops up, but the test runner is able to advance to the next SpecFlow step.

**Step definition for `Then I should see the validation error alert`:**

```
[Then(@"I should see the validation error alert")]
public void ThenIShouldSeeTheValidationErrorAlert()
{
    var alert = StepHelper.GetAlertBox();

    Assert.IsTrue(alert.Message.Contains("An error has occurred"),
        "An alert was found, but contained the wrong message ('{0}')", alert.Message);
}
```

Here I use the `StepHelper.GetAlertBox()` method I created earlier to get a handle on the `WatiN.Core.Native.Windows.Window` object representing the alert box. Then it's a simple `Assert.IsTrue` ensuring the message displayed in the alert is actually our "Validation failed" message (we have other alert's on this page as well).

Lastly, we need to close the alert box.

**Step definition for `When I click OK in the validation error alert`:**

```
[When(@"I click OK in the validation error alert")]
public void WhenIClickOKInTheValidationErrorAlert()
{
    var alert = StepHelper.GetAlertBox();

    Assert.IsTrue(alert.Message.Contains("An error has occurred"),
        "An alert was found, but contained the wrong message ('{0}')", alert.Message);

    alert.ForceClose();
}
```

Here we just get the alert box object from the helper, and call `ForceClose` to dismiss the alert box, since clicking "OK" or the "X" button in the upper right essentially does the same thing.